# Running two ports for redis

Tags: parallel-processing, redis

Suppose i host Redis server on two ports in same machine , will it be helpful for me to  perform read queries to Redis in parallel? I know that redis is single threaded hence the queries can be concurrent and not parallel. Does adding an extra port on same machine help?

Answer (score 1):

Every Redis database (instance/process/server/shard) uses at most a single network port and cannot be configured with more. However, you can run multiple instances on the same server, each with its own port, to better utilize the compute resources.

Comment: Do you have any approximate  idea about how many instance can perform well in parallel on a box with 2 cores and sufficient memory? I am guessing atleast 2 must perform well.